# alamofire swiftyjson returns no response on first attempt swift 3.1

Tags: swift3, alamofire, swifty-json

I am new to swift 3.1.
I am using Alamofire, Swiftyjson.
On clicking a button, I am getting a response from url. But, my problem is, on the first click no response is returned and on the second click the proper response is returned.
Please help.
Thanks in advance!!

Below is my code snippet.

```
let url = "myurl"

Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in

            if (responseData.result.value) != nil
            {
                let response = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
                //print("RESPONSE == \(response)")

                if let dictResponse = response.dictionaryObject
                //print(dictResponse!)
                {
                    self.strRes = dictResponse["response"] as! String
                    print(self.strRes)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you wait after your first button click because it takes sometime to get response from the Api on basis of your net speed

Comment: yes, I did that too. but as soon as I click the button for the second time, the response is returned. @Nirav D

Comment: Put the break point in your button action and check how many time code is getting executing

Comment: I've checked. For the first time, it does not enter in Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
and goes to the last } of the code snippet. And on the second time it enters in if (responseData.result.value) != nil, and executes properly

Comment: have you solved this @A21?